# How to build a function to extract data from column names over a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I am trying to extract data from column names over a large number of data frames contained in a list. The last column in each data frame will contain a unique number that I am trying to extract.

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, xx123xx = NA)

df2 <- data.frame(X = 1, Y = 2, xx456xx = NA)

dfList <- list(df1,df2)
```

Then I would like to build a function that does the following for each data frame in the list:

Extract the data in the column names

```
df1[,3] <- colnames(df1)[3]
```

Remove the non numeric portions of the data

```
df1[,3] <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df1[,3])
```

Such that I can do this for all data frames in the list using

```
lappy(dfList, function)
```

And

```
print(dfList)
```

Returns the desired output:

```
[[1]]
  A B xx123xx
1 1 2      123

[[2]]
  X Y xx456xx
1 1 2      456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can write the helper function

```
foo <- function(x) {
  id <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", tail(names(x), 1))
  x[, length(x)] <- id
  x
}
```

and then use it with `lapply` to transform the list

```
dfList  <- lapply(dfList, foo)
# [[1]]
#   A B xx123xx
# 1 1 2     123
# 
# [[2]]
#   X Y xx456xx
# 1 1 2     456
```

Comment: Is there a way that the end list can still contain the original data in columns A,B and X,Y

Comment: `dfList` still contains all the data. It hasn't been changed. What exactly is your desired output? Perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Updated to hopefully be more clear. Thank you for your help and input

Comment: `map(dfList, ~\`[<-\`(.x, 3, value = parse_number(names(.x)[3])))` if one wants to be crazy

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` with `last_col` (to select the last column) and `cur_column`(`name` of the currently selected column). `parse_number` extracts the numbers/digits from a string:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

dfList |>
    map(\(x)
        mutate(x,
               across(last_col(),
                              \(x) parse_number(cur_column())
                      )
               )
        )

[[1]]
  A B xx123xx
1 1 2     123

[[2]]
  X Y xx456xx
1 1 2     456
```